# Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings

Tags: .net, docker, nat

Hello i am trying to create a container  using a wrapper over `Docker.DotNet` `Api` .The problem is that while on one computer it works without problem on the other it throws the following exception :

```
'Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"failed to create endpoint flamboyant_lalande on network nat: Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings"}
```

The weird thing is that i have tried to open different images using the `API` and i get the same error.

What could it be?

**P.S** Outside of using of this `API` i can create containers without problems.